# Triggering method from within a loop with Python and Pycord

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I'm playing around with Pycord and trying to send a message to a channel X for each element in an array.

The following class will throw a `TypeError: MyClient.on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'` indicating that `MyClient.on_ready()` needs 2 arguments, one for `self`, one for `message`, but every example on how to pass arguments to class methods were only sending the argument.

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    async def on_ready(self, message):
        channel = self.get_channel(123)  # Your channel ID goes here
        await channel.send(message)

client = MyClient()

for comment in comments:   
    if  comment['data']['parent_id'].startswith("t1") and comment['data']['name'] not in comments_json:
        wop = comment['data']['permalink']
        client.on_ready(wop)
        client.run("xxx")
```

What am I missing?

*EDIT*: Added changes from comment, now error message reads as follow:

```
coroutine 'MyClient.on_ready' was never awaited
  client.on_ready(wop)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 352, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: MyClient.on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Comment: You should create an instance of the class before calling class methods. `client = MyClient()` before the `for` loop, then you can call `client.on_ready(wop)`

Comment: @Jyr added your changes, good catch. Nonetheless is still not working :/

Comment: From the docs the way to run is calling `client.run("token")` after instantiating the class. Also `on_ready()` will only be called once. Have a look at some examples https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got is because `on_ready` doesn't take any arguments

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for, gets an channel object and sends an array (also subclassed just like the code you send)

```py
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from typing import Iterable, Optional, Any


class MyClient(discord.Client):

    # > trying to send a message to a channel X for each element in an array.
    def __init__(
        self,
        channel_to_send: int,
        array: Iterable,
        *,
        loop: Optional[asyncio.AbstractEventLoop] = None,
        **options: Any
    ):
        self.channel_to_send = channel_to_send
        self.array = array
        super().__init__(loop=loop, **options)

    async def on_ready(self):
        channel_ = await self.fetch_channel(self.channel_to_send)
        for element in self.array:
            await channel_.send(element)


channel_id = 917803321929134133 # Replace this with that of yours 
array = ["foo", "bar", "this", "is", "working"] # Replace this with that of yours

client = MyClient(channel_id, array)
client.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```

Result :
[image: result]